# Cannot boot to USB Boot-Repair stick

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have W10 and 2 other Debian-based partitions on an UEFI/GPT SSD and am well used to using Boot-Repair(BR). As of this morning, without any relevant previous activity by me yesterday, my system just goes to a Grub2 > prompt when I turn my system on.

So as usual, I get out my trusted BR USB stick, however this time I could not  boot from it, although I have recreated the BR stick several times using all possible MBR/GPT options using Rufus, with no luck.

If I interrupt the Boot process with F12, I get a choice of Samsung EVO SSD, Windows Boot Manager, and various EFI boot options(USB HDD, USB CD-ROM etc.). Selecting anything but WBM gets the same GRUB2> prompt, but selecting WBM gets at least W10 loaded. I also turned Safe Boot off

Suspecting a BIOS problem, I reflashed the BIOS without any change.

So my status is now:

1. Grub obviously damaged, no Linux system can be started
2. Cannot do a Boot Repair as no boot from USB stick possible.

Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer so please treat this as a comment. I had an almost similar problem yesterday which is solved this afternoon.

My system has 3 primary partitions (Recovery, System Reserved, W7) and logical partitions for, among of which, W10 and Xubuntu 17.04. The W10 partition got erroneous and I deleted it, I thought it will be okay since I believed I can still boot to W7 or Xubuntu. I didn't ran `update-grub` nor `grub-install`. But, when I restarted, it is showing `GRUB2> prompt`.

Fortunately I have a couple of USB sticks with live/persistent USBs (Ubuntu 16.10 and Tahrpup), so I plugged each one of them, but the screen kept showing `GRUB2> prompt`. I did noticed, however, a couple of days ago when it's a cold boot (turned off laptop, plugin the USB, and press the power on), the laptop skips the USB drives (it's an old laptop so the ports are probably rusty).

So when the screen shows the infamous `GRUB2> prompt`, I plugged in one bootable USB, restart the laptop (instead of turned it off), and voila! The laptop reads from USB again. Next step involved `update-grub` nor `grub-install` and boot is good again.

Another workaround would probably booting a GNU/Linux ISO from Windows. I haven't tested it, so I can't comment much, but from a quick research it seems doable using third-party bootloader, or even better: using Windows own Disk Management GUI to create/attach VHD containing GNU/Linux ISO.

Comment: The actual Boot-Repair ISO is now older, have you tried booting with the current Ubuntu live installer and adding Boot-Repair to that - 2nd option? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0):

Try putting my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on a USB flash drive or CD-R. (Download links for both types of images are on that page.) If Secure Boot is disabled on the computer, rEFInd should boot and give you options to boot both Windows and Ubuntu, and if Ubuntu boots properly, you'll then be able to perform better diagnosis and repair in Ubuntu. You could also try Ubuntu on one USB drive and your Ubuntu installation/emergency disk on another one. That combination might enable you to boot the Ubuntu emergency disk, if you can get rEFInd to start.

If rEFInd won't start from the external medium, then Secure Boot might be enabled, or there might be something weird going on that's preventing the computer from booting from external media. This could be a physical problem (a loose wire, corroded contact, etc.) or some obscure firmware setting to prevent it from booting external media. You might use the Windows [reboot-to-firmware](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5831-boot-uefi-firmware-settings-inside-windows-10-a.html) feature to boot into the firmware to check its options (or enter the firmware settings using whatever keystroke does that for your computer as you power on). In case it's a physical problem, switching your USB drive from one USB plug to another one might help. Removing any USB hubs is also worth trying; a hub might have developed a fault or simply worked its cable loose.

You might also try using the GRUB shell (that `grub>` prompt you're seeing) to locate the GRUB configuration file and continue the boot process. [This article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-GRUB2-features/index.html) I wrote a few years back describes how to do this; see the "Using the GRUB 2 Shell" section. [Here's another article](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-Linux) on this subject, that goes into more detail.

Yet another final and desperate approach is to install rEFInd from Windows. The Windows installation process for rEFInd is a bit tedious (see [the documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/installing.html#windows)), but it can be done; and if this works, it should enable you to boot both Windows and Ubuntu. Don't bother with this if rEFInd starts up from a USB drive but can't boot Ubuntu, though; this is intended as a solution if you can't get the USB drive to boot at all.

Note that one possible reason for some of the symptoms you're seeing is that the Ubuntu partition may have been damaged or even deleted. If so, recovery is likely to be difficult or even impossible. You can check some of the basics using Windows partitioning tools; however, unless you install filesystem drivers, you won't be able to dig into the Ubuntu installation, just verify that the partition(s) still exist. You may want to try this before you invest too much effort into getting past the GRUB hurdle; if your Ubuntu filesystem is wiped out, you won't clear that hurdle without re-installing or doing some major repair work.

Comment: @th.sigit @ Rod Smith

Comment: As I said, I have tried creating BR will all 3 of the Rufus 2.16 options for the partition table on the USB, nothing works